# how to receive numbers with input and return only even numbers in javascript & jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

how to receive numbers with input and return only even numbers in javascript & jquery?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var nums = $("#nums").val();
        var numsf = nums.split(',');
        var res = numsf.join(", ");
        var even = 
        $("p").append(even + "<br>");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello homework question!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/vtvmbwau/ See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use modulus 2 to detect if it is an even number

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var nums = parseInt($("#nums").val());
        var isEven = nums % 2 == 0;
        if(isEven){
            $("p").append(nums);
        }
    });
});
```

**Update**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var nums = $("#nums").val();
    var numsf = nums.split(',');
    var evens = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numsf.length; i++) {
      if (parseInt(numsf[i]) % 2 == 0) {
        evens.push(numsf[i]);
      }
    }
    var res = evens.join(", ");
    $("p").append(res + "<br>");
  });
});
```

Comment: @VateX, how? Does an exception occur? Did you mean something else? Can you replicate it in a fiddle?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, sorry, meant Vatex

Comment: @AmmarCSE : Our solutions had a small issue, but I noticed it only when I was testing your code. if we provide something like '1a' in the textbox, it also gets added in the result. Now I realized I made a mistakes. I am really sorry, and I have changed my vote. I added `!isNaN(_this)` to the `if` condition.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan, even if you downvoted, there is no hard feelings. I just want an explanation of why a downvote occured so I can correct my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This fixes your issue. I have provided the demo link.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/vtvmbwau/)

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var nums = $("#nums").val();
        var numsf = nums.split(','); //array of comma separated values
        var evens = [];
        //loops through the array. see documentation for jQuery.each()
        $.each(numsf,function(i, _this){
            if (!isNaN(_this) && parseInt(_this) % 2 == 0)
                evens.push(_this);
        });
        var res = evens.toString();
        $("p").append(res + "<br>");
    });
});
```

[jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: It'd be much more useful if you explained how this answers the question, how the code works and what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var numsf = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

  $.each(numsf, function(a, b) {
    if (b % 2 == 0) {
      alert(b);
      return b;
    }

  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally suggest the following – written on the assumption that the element with the `id="nums"` is meant to take a comma-separated string of numbers:

```
// binding an anonymous function tot he click event
// of the element with 'id="submit"', passing the
// event ('e') into the function:
$("#submit").click(function (e) {

    // preventing any default behaviour of the
    // element's click event:
    e.preventDefault();

    // updating the text of the <p> element(s)
    // (it would be better, in practice, to use
    // a more specific selector):
    $('p').text(function () {

        // splitting the value of the '#nums' element on the
        // comma (',') character to form an array; using
        // Array.prototype.filter() to filter that array:
        return $('#nums').val().split(',').filter(function (n){
            // the first argument to the anonymous function
            // (here 'n') is the array element of the array
            // over which we're iterating.

            // we trim the number-string (removing leading
            // and trailing spaces), and then use parseInt()
            // to convert that to a number in base 10 (the
            // second, the radix, argument to parseInt());
            // if the remainder of the division of that number
            // by two is 0 then the number is even and
            // the assessment evaluates to true, so we
            // keep that number (discarding those numbers
            // for which the assessment evaluates to false):
            return parseInt(n.trim(), 10) % 2 === 0;

        // joining the filtered-array back together:
        }).join(', ');
    });
});
```

```js
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('p').text(function() {
    return $('#nums').val().split(',').filter(function(n) {
      return parseInt(n.trim(), 10) % 2 === 0;
    }).join(', ');
  });
});
```

```css
p::before {
  content: 'Even numbers: ';
  display: block;
  color: #999;
}
p:empty::before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <fieldset>
    <label>Enter comma-separated numbers:
      <input id="nums" type="text" placeholder="1,2,3,4..." />
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<p></p>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hx7c5oz0/), for experimentation/development, etc.

Incidentally, this can be done similarly in plain JavaScript – without the use of a library, such as jQuery – with the following:

```
// getting the element with 'id="submit"' and binding an
// anonymous function as the click event-handler, passing
// the event ('e') into the function:
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    // preventing any default actions the element might have:
    e.preventDefault();

    // retrieving the <form> associated with the clicked element,
    // then getting the next element sibling, and setting its
    // text-content:
    this.form.nextElementSibling.textContent = document

    // getting the element with the id of 'nums':
    .getElementById('nums')

    // retrieving its value, splitting that value on comma
    // characters to form an array:
    .value.split(',')

    // filtering that array, using Array.prototype.filter():
    .filter(function (n) {
        // exactly the same as above:
        return parseInt(n.trim(), 10) % 2 === 0;
    }).join(', ');
});
```

```js
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.form.nextElementSibling.textContent = document
    .getElementById('nums')
    .value.split(',').filter(function(n) {
      return parseInt(n.trim(), 10) % 2 === 0;
    }).join(', ');
});
```

```css
p::before {
  content: 'Even numbers: ';
  display: block;
  color: #999;
}
p:empty::before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <fieldset>
    <label>Enter comma-separated numbers:
      <input id="nums" type="text" placeholder="1,2,3,4..." />
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<p></p>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hx7c5oz0/1), for experimentation/development, etc.

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).
  - [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
  - [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
  - [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).
- jQuery:

  - [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
  - [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).